# Could not import settings 'live.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named billiard.exceptions

Tags: django

I'm trying to setting my django project in production on Ubuntu (EC2 instance) and I'm getting the error below. My path is 100% right, and I have looked up other stackoverflow questions with the same sort of issues but no of them seemed to help. I'm thinking I may have a different issue.

Can anyone spot anything wrong or know my issue that give this error?

**Running Django 1.5

Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS**

Error:

**File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/_*init*_.py", line 132, in _*init*_
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[client 37.191.99.202] ImportError: Could not import settings 'live.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named billiard.exceptions**

**wsgi**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/srv/projects/liveSMS')
sys.path.append('/srv/projects/liveSMS.live')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "live.settings")


import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

site (domain.com not real domain)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName  domain.com
   ServerAlias domain.com

   DocumentRoot /srv/projects/liveSMS/public

   WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/projects/liveSMS/apache/django.wsgi
   <Directory /srv/projects/liveSMS/>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

    Alias /robots.txt /srv/projects/liveSMS/public/robots.txt
    Alias /static /srv/projects/liveSMS/static

     ErrorLog /srv/projects/liveSMS/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Full Error

```
[Tue Mar 19 10:31:40 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Tue Mar 19 10:31:40 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202] ImportError: Could not import settings 'live/settings' (Is it on sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported.
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202] mod_wsgi (pid=1488): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/projects/liveSMS/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     self._setup(name)
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Tue Mar 19 10:39:14 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202] ImportError: Could not import settings 'live.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named billiard.exceptions
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202] mod_wsgi (pid=1656): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/projects/liveSMS/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     self._setup(name)
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Tue Mar 19 11:14:53 2013] [error] [client 37.191.99.202] ImportError: Could not import settings 'live.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named billiard.exceptions
```

Comment: I installed using apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi?

Comment: I don't know what uwsgi is sorry.

Comment: Try to add the paths to your apache config with help of **WSGIPythonPath**. Use : as a separator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Do you have a full dump of error (lines but error in django/conf/_init_.py)?

Comment: I just tried WSGIPythonPath /srv/projects/liveWireSMS but same error. I'm not using vertualenv as this is production by the way and hosting one site

Comment: updated with error @ sergzach thanks

Comment: Try to add the path to $PYTHONPATH system variable (use : delimiter). For example in .bashrc (the file in a home of a user) for a user who starts Apache: PYTHONPATH='/srv/projects/liveSMS/:/srv/projects/liveSMS.live/'. Then logout, login and restart Apache.

Comment: I got the same error sorry.

Comment: whats the No module named billiard.exceptions at the end is this relevant to the issue?

Comment: Yes, billiard module must be in PYTHONPATH too.

Comment: I can import Django in python shell but when I try to import settings I get No module named liveSMS

Comment: Because liveSMS is not in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: OK I see maybe I'm adding it wrong. I added PYTHONPATH='/srv/projects/liveSMS/:/srv/projects/liveSMS.live/' to /ect/.bashrc anythere else this needs to go?

Comment: Check in your interpreter: import sys\nsys.path

Comment: does the folder with the wsgi need to have a __init__.py also?

Comment: Probably it is created automatically. What about sys.path from python shell? Are all required paths in the list?

Comment: how do you print them out? I'm in the python shell done import sys

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26457/discussion-between-sergzach-and-spike)

Comment: got it they show: ['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

Comment: OK, you can also try to add to PYTHONPATH from a linux console (probably it's temporary, will be losed after you log out): export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/srv/projects/liveSMS/:/srv/projects/liveSMS.live/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably in your configuration the paths /srv/projects/liveSMS and /srv/projects/liveSMS.live must be in PYTHONPATH variable.

For example, you can add it permanently to a .bashrc file of a user who starts Apache webserver:

PYTHONPATH='/srv/projects/liveSMS/:/srv/projects/liveSMS.live/'.

I'm not sure that the proposed solution is best. But it could work.

Comment: I got it working by creating a new user and adding WSGIDaemonProcess DOMAIN user=USER group=USER processes=1 threads=15 maximum-requests=10000 python-path=/srv/liveSMS/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages python-eggs=/srv/liveSMS/run/eggs
WSGIProcessGroup DjangoWeb
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/liveSMS/app/conf/apache/django.wsgi

Comment: @Spike Was 'python-path' a problem? If you remove it does it work or not?

Comment: Yes, seems it was the user it was running on. I created a new user changed to run under that user, then added bashrc python path to that user as you showed me. this seem to resolve this issue.